# How do you implement functions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a user interface with a series of images and text boxes, and I'm wondering why I can't define a function for each image and text box, and pass in a variable for each.

Here's the text function I want to define:

```
   func textBox(textIn: String) {
    Text("\(textIn)")
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .offset(y: 65)
}
```

and when I want to call the function it tells me

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {

textBox(textIn: "Test!")
```

I've only been programming for a few months, and I've been working in Swift for less than a week, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

Thanks in advance

Miles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is to return a View from your function, like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                textBox(textIn: "Test!")
            }
        }
    }
}

func textBox(textIn: String) -> AnyView {
    AnyView(Text("\(textIn)")
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .offset(y: 65)
    )
}
}
```

it even works with this:

```
func textBox(textIn: String) -> some View {
    Text("\(textIn)")
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .offset(y: 65)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a disadvantage to using some View instead of specifying a view?